# process can not open pdf file c#

Tags: c#, windows, pdf-conversion

In a Windows application I need to run another one application that's tetpdflib. That tetpdflib runs in command prompt only. When I drag and drop exe to the command prompt it will execute. Here is my code:

```
Process tetmlProcess = new Process();
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\sw_chn\Documents\PDFlib\TET 5.0 32-bit\bin";
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\sw_chn\Documents\PDFlib\TET 5.0 32-bit\bin\tet.exe";
string args1 = @"tet -m wordplus D:\DailyWork\March\JOURNAL-ISSUE_6_3924-3930.pdf";
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = args1;
tetmlProcess.Start();
StreamReader news = tetmlProcess.StandardError;
string err = news.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(err);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I had following error:

> could not open PDF file 'tet' for reading

How to recover from this?

Comment: Do you really need "tet" as first argument? (so `tet.exe tet -m wordplus ...`)

Comment: Remove `"tet"` from your `args1` string

Comment: Thats the command why need to remove.

Comment: @MalathiMals, no, the command is in `Process.StartInfo.FileName`. The Arguments is what you write *after* you wrote the file name (That is: `-m wordplus D:\DailyWork\March\JOURNAL-ISSUE_6_3924-3930.pdf` )

Comment: sting str = D:\DailyWork\March\JOURNAL-ISSUE_6_3924-3930.pdf                  string args1 = @"-m wordplus" + " " + str;
                tetmlProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = args1;                                             what is the error on that? again i got same error as pdf could not open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Start Arguments` contains the Program Name again which leads to this error.

Simply change your code

```
Process tetmlProcess = new Process();
// ...
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\sw_chn\Documents\PDFlib\TET 5.0 32-bit\bin";
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\sw_chn\Documents\PDFlib\TET 5.0 32-bit\bin\tet.exe";
// removing "tet" in Arguments
string args1 = @"-m wordplus D:\DailyWork\March\JOURNAL-ISSUE_6_3924-3930.pdf";
tetmlProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = args1;
tetmlProcess.Start();
// ...
```

---

### Conclusion

The [manual](http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/TET-5.0-manual.pdf) contains example like this

`tet --format utf16 --outfile file.utf16 file.pdf`

Here is `tet` mapped as environment variable in the system and stands for the full path of the application.

Comment: sting str = D:\DailyWork\March\JOURNAL-ISSUE_6_3924-3930.pdf string args1 = @"-m wordplus" + " " + str; tetmlProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = args1; what is the error on that? again i got same error as pdf could not open